# How do I add a jar using sparklyr?

Tags: sparklyr

When I try to access a Hive table using Rstudio and sparklyr using this code:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client") # got from ambari spark2 configs
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = config, version = '2.1.0')

library(DBI)
tabTweets <- dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT * FROM tweets0 LIMIT 10")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Failed to fetch data: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

This is because tweets0 was created using JsonSerDe. It is easily fixed, for example, when encountered using Hive CLI by:

```
Add jar /usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

so how do I do an equivalent add jar using sparklyr?

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
spark_dependencies <- function(spark_version, scala_version, ...) {
  sparklyr::spark_dependency(
    jars = c(
      system.file(
        sprintf("/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar"),
    package = "JsonSerDe"
      )
    )
  )
}
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  sparklyr::register_extension(pkgname)
}

library(JsonSerDe)
```

but still same error and library(JsonSerDe) gives:

```
Error in library(JsonSerDe) : there is no package called ‘JsonSerDe’
```

I see nothing in the Spark log about adding a dependency.

Comment: Did you create/are you using an R package called `JsonSerDe`?  You can add jars to sparklyr via the config option in `spark_connect`, specifically, the list named `sparklyr.jars.default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not a sparklyr one: it was a setting in tez.lib.uris. Changed it to:

```
/hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/tez/tez.tar.gz,hdfs://master.royble.co.uk:8020/jars/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

(Note: no space after comma and hdfs path).
However issue of:

```
Error in library(JsonSerDe) : there is no package called ‘JsonSerDe’
```

still stands and I will accept an answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

You can supply jar using spark config. Below worked for us.

```
config[["sparklyr.jars.default"]] <- "/usr/lib/jars/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
```

OR

`config[["sparklyr.jars.default"]] <- "hdfs://master.royble.co.uk:8020/jars/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar`"